# C# executing code from one button in another

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've one button - button1click and textbox in which when i type something and press enter, i'd like to run code from button1click.

How can I do it without copying entire code from button1click into EnterPressed?

```
private void button1click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Some Code
}


void EnterPressed(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        Execute code from button1
    }
}
```

Maybe something like that? But I'm getting errors...

```
void EnterPressed(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        button1click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    }
}
```

Comment: wondering ,setting the **AcceptButton** property of the form would have resulted in the same behaviour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just have button1_click call a method and then you can call that same method from anywhere you want to.  So in your example:

```
private void button1click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       Foo();
}


void EnterPressed(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        Foo();
    }
}

void Foo()
{
    //Do Something
}
```

I personally wouldn't manually call another control's event.

Comment: Your last line is too much FUD, there's nothing wrong with doing this.

Comment: Tnx :) You're right with this calling another contro's event.

Comment: @Hans, personal preference I guess. For readability purposes, I prefer to actually call a method rather than a button click event in cases such as this.

Answer (score 1):

```
void EnterPressed(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        button1click(sender, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: @abatishchev: I don't know what was wrong, but thanks for making it correct :)